# command line parameter while

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parameters

I want to run command line with patameters to make it wait for connection then do "gpupdate /force" and then nofity user the job is done. The thing I am stuck at is making it wait for connection.

```
cmd /c echo Connect a network cable. & *something* & echo n | gpupdate /force & msg * Done.
```

If *something* was following code then it would work:

```
:top
ping -n 1 site.com >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    goto top
)
```

but I don't know how would I write it on 1 line as a parameter.

How would I make it work the way I wish? Alternative solutions are welcome as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your aversion to a batch script. But the following one liner should work.

```
@echo Connect a network cable.&cmd /q /c "for /l %N in () do ping -n 1 site.com >nul&&exit"&echo echo n^|gpupdate /force&msg * Done.
```

The key bit is `cmd /q /c "for /l %N in () do ping -n 1 site.com >nul&&exit"`. A new CMD.EXE process is created that enters an infinite FOR loop. It continuously pings the site until it is successful. The EXIT command only executes when PING was successful because of the `&&` operator. Once EXIT executes, control is returned to the parent CMD.EXE process.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it all a batch file?

```
@echo off
echo Connect a network cable. 
:top
ping -n 1 site.com >nul || goto :top
echo Connected.
gpupdate /force 
msg * Done.
```

Comment: As it would be ideal to run it only with a keyboard macro on any computer - not only those that have this file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LukAss741 - And how exactly would the various computers get the macro defined? Perhaps a file? It seems to me you are going to need a file regardless, unless you expect users to key-in a complicated command.

Comment: By pressing keys: win c m d   / c   e c h o   C o n and so on... Entered by a scanner after scanning qr, aztec or some other code. That is the reason why I wanted to do it only as a parameter of command line.